# Python Method Returning None

Tags: python, return

I'm having a very odd problem. I wrote a method that determines the degree of a formula describing a set of numbers, when given the said set. The method is fairly simple, I've added in a couple of lines for debugging purposes:

```
def getdeg(numlist, cnt): #get the degree of the equation describing numlist
    count = cnt #initial run should be with cnt as 0
    templist = []
    for i in range(len(numlist) - 1): #exclude the last item (which doesn't have an item after it)
        templist.append(numlist[i+1] - numlist[i]) #append the val of index i+1 minus index i
    count += 1
    print(templist)
    if not allEqual(templist):
        print("Not all equal, iterating again")
        getdeg(templist, count)
    else:
        print(count)
        return count

def allEqual(numlist):
    if len(numlist) == 1:
        return True
    for i in range(len(numlist) -1):
        if not (numlist[i] == numlist[i+1]):
            return False

    return True
```

Now, I'm running this on a set of numbers I KNOW to be described by a 3rd-degree equation, like so:

```
x = getdeg([2, 8, 9, 11, 20], 0)
print(x)
```

Fairly simple, yes? Except when you run this, it prints out the following:

```
[6, 1, 2, 9]
Not all equal, iterating again
[-5, 1, 7]
Not all equal, iterating again
[6, 6]
3
None
```

Everything is looking good, right up until that "None." What is it doing there? I would assume that the `else` conditional isn't being executed, but it's printing out 3 just fine, so it obviously is. That also means that the program "knows" what the value of `count` is, but it's not returning it right. Could someone enlighten me as to what on earth is going on?

Answer (score 3):

```
if not allEqual(templist):
    print("Not all equal, iterating again")
    getdeg(templist, count)
```

Remember, when a method recursively calls itself, you still need to explicitly `return` the value if you want a value to be returned.

```
if not allEqual(templist):
    print("Not all equal, iterating again")
    return getdeg(templist, count)
```

Comment: Ah, god. Recursion ****s me over yet again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a value in the if clause as well.

```
return getdeg(templist, count)
```